# conversion failed string to int using case when then in sql

Tags: sql

I use case when in my sql query as follows,

```
SELECT 
         CASE 
            WHEN Grade = 'Diesel' THEN 4
            WHEN Grade = 'Petrol' THEN 5

       END as Grade
      ,sales

  FROM testTableA as tta

  INNER JOIN testTableB ttb on ttb.productid =  tta.Grade
```

When I run above I get `"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Diesel' to data type int.`" error.
I tried Cast(tta.Grade, int) too but no luck.. What Im doing wrong here?

**Edit**

```
testTableA : column grade is varchar.
testTableB: column productid is int
```

Comment: In general always avoid using a alias with the same name as the table name or column name some SQL optimizers can do wierd stuff then becuase they dont know if it is a alias, table or column

Comment: I think the error comes from the join, can you try `on convert(varchar, ttA.productid) =  tta.Grade`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger no,  ttb.productid is int column

Comment: @Ratha Yeah, but tta.Grade isn't, so when you equate them the string column is implicitly converted to int. This is what fails.

Comment: @HoneyBadger in that case error goes, but return zero entries, which is wrong

Comment: @Ratha, in that case you got the wrong attributes in the join

Comment: please show the `CREATE TABLE` commands of the two tables so we can see the structure.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I edited my question with required info. I want to join two tables, one column Grade is varchar and productid column is int, That is why im using when condition to get integer values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you'd like to join on the output of the case statement, then you should be this:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Grade = 'Diesel' THEN 4
    WHEN Grade = 'Petrol' THEN 5
 END as Grade
,sales
FROM testTableA as tta
INNER JOIN testTableB ttb 
ON ttb.productid =  CASE 
    WHEN tta.Grade = 'Diesel' THEN 4
    WHEN tta.Grade = 'Petrol' THEN 5
END
```

or wrap `tta` into a subquery to avoid duplicating the same logic

Comment: Thanks THis is what I wnated. So I can avoid first WHEN condition, which I dont need. I used that because, I wanted to do join

Answer (score 1):

You would have to return string value because `Grade` has string value & your `ELSE` part returning them also & `case` expression will return only one type :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Grade = 'Diesel' THEN '4'
             WHEN Grade = 'Petrol' THEN '5'
             ELSE Grade 
        END) as Grade,
 . . .
```

**EDIT :** Join also cause the conversation issue , so you have to do some conversation

```
SELECT ttb.Grade, sales
FROM testTableA as tta CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CASE WHEN tta.Grade = 'Diesel' THEN 4
                    WHEN tta.Grade = 'Petrol' THEN 5
               END)
     ) tt(grade) INNER JOIN
    testTableB ttb
    ON ttb.productid = tt.Grade;
```

Comment: This also gives same issue

Answer (score 1):

Given your code sample, there are two possibilities:

- `Grade` is a number, and the error is coming from the `case` comparing the value to `'Diesel'`.
- `ProductId` is a number, and the error is coming from the `on` condition when `Grade` has a value of `'Diesel'`.

Of course, there are other possibilities, such as the table references really being views.

There is not enough information to determine which of these is actually happening.  However, you know what the data types of your columns are, so you can immediately determine the problem.

If I had to guess, it would be the `join` condition.  Joining something called `productId` to something called `grade` is suspicious.

Comment: ProductId is int column, Grade is the one I get from string to int using When condition

Comment: @Ratha . . . So the second situation appears to be the problem.  Find the write join keys and use them.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments, I think you may be looking for this:

```
SELECT 
         CASE 
            WHEN Grade = 'Diesel' THEN 4
            WHEN Grade = 'Petrol' THEN 5

       END as Grade
      ,sales

  FROM testTableA as tta

  INNER JOIN testTableB ttb on ttb.productid =  CASE 
                                                    WHEN tta.Grade = 'Diesel' THEN 4
                                                    WHEN tta.Grade = 'Petrol' THEN 5
                                                 END
```

Comment: Thanks I beleive, i should omit first CASE statement which is additional

Comment: @Ratha, yeah, if you need it, you might as well just select ttb.productid